# how to extract encrypted message digest from asn.1 in PHP

Tags: php, asn.1, phpasn1

I use PHPASN1 to decode an ASN.1 string that is the signature of a PDF document. I have the following structure.

```
SEQUENCE : [2 children]
|-OBJECT IDENTIFIER : Signed data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.2)
|-[0] CONTEXT-SPECIFIC (0XA0) : [1 child]
|--SEQUENCE : [5 children]
|---INTEGER : 1
|---SET : [1 child]
|----SEQUENCE : [2 children]

....
....
....
....

|-----SEQUENCE : [2 children]
|------OBJECT IDENTIFIER : RSA Encryption
|------NULL : NULL
|-----OCTET STRING : 7D63AB9BBF07C60E581FDEA971AF6BAF87D0CB757E99F307C7A4313210F53E62FA51290B52009E7F3B02424A4B630C7E097477E019E69DE6B2B8A6269B0EED0BBFDF207BF8965859FF13BEBF97918B9CA82AC22CF11C1BEE9579DBC84C9A0D6194C4FFB0759852BECABB3737123176A11017A56554B2CB01861E82B0C0D3B196
```

I want to get the encrypted message digest. How do I obtain it?

Comment: The final octet string after the final `RSA Encryption` likely is one encrypted digest. Whether it's the one you are looking for or not (and instead probably that of an embedded time stamp), is not clear from your excerpt. You might want to take a CMS RFC and check the ASN.1 definition there.

Comment: Many thanks. I want to sign and verify a pdf document in php. I use TCPDF to sign but it cannot verify. So I have to verify by myself. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not in php; I understood your question to first of all  be about which part of your ASN.1 dump contains the *encrypted message digest*.